# Clearing form input in Meteor

Tags: forms, meteor

I have tried multiple options that I have found on SO and elsewhere for clearing form inputs, all listed below in the code, but nothing seems to work.  Is there anything specific about this form that would determine which one I should use?

```
<template name="CompanyAdd">
    <div>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{> inputAutocomplete settings=companySettings id="companyAdd" name="companyAdd" class="input-xlarge" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add Company"}}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default company-add">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template


Template.CompanyAdd.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var selection = $(e.target).find('[id=companyAdd]').val();

        var company = {
            ticker: selection
        };

        if(Companies.findOne({ticker:selection})) {
            console.log("Do nothing");
        } else {
            Meteor.call('companyAdd', company, function(error, result) {
            });
        }
        //event.target.reset();
        //e.target.reset();
        //target.text.value = '';
        //template.find("form").reset();
        //document.getElementById("companyAdd").reset();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have

```
var selection = $(e.target).find('[id=companyAdd]').val();
```

That is the input you want to clear and that - I assume - works, I would do:

```
var field = $(e.target).find('[id=companyAdd]');
var selection = field.val();
...
field.val('')
```

Otherwise if you wish to reset all form, go for @JeremyK`s #reset.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt:

```
e.target.reset();
```

should work fine.  If it is not working, check if there are any errors in the console and report back here.

> [The handler function receives two arguments: **event**, an object with
>   information about the event, and **template**, a template instance for the
>   template where the handler is defined.](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#eventmaps)

In your code above you define your handler like this:

```
'submit form': function(e) {
```

You have named the **event** argument `e`, and discarded the **template** argument.

- `e` is has information about the event
- `e.target` is the form element (The event was defined on `'submit form'`)
- `e.target.reset` succeeds because reset is a valid function to call on a form.

Briefly, your other attempts failed because:

- `event.target.reset();`    event is not defined or passed in, at least not with the name `event` (you used `e`)
- `target.text.value = '';`  target is an undefined variable
- `template.find("form").reset();`  this fails because `template` is undefined.  If you change your handler definition to receive the template variable, this will work (change `'submit form': function(e)` to `'submit form': function(e, template)`
- `document.getElementById("companyAdd").reset();`  This fails because the element with the id `companyAdd` is the input element, not the form, so `.reset()` is undefined.  You could change this to `document.getElementById("companyAdd").text.value = ''`

Comment: Thanks for all the great detail.  I tried again with `e.target.reset()` and it still doesn't work, the input value remains after executing.  There are no errors in the console though.